# Unsafe Class-loading Issue?

Tags: java, unsafe

Unsafe has a method to ensure that classes are initialized:

```
Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Class) line: not available [native method]
```

I suspect that this type of initialization doesn't lock on the class like regular java class-loading because I've occasionally bumped into some impossible situations. I can give more details later if needed, but does anyone know if class-loading using Unsafe has quirks like that?

Btw, here's a short stack trace of how that class gets loaded up:

```
Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Class) line: not available [native method]               
UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(Field, boolean) line: 25
ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(Field, boolean) line: 122    
Field.acquireFieldAccessor(boolean) line: 918    
Field.getFieldAccessor(Object) line: 899               
Field.get(Object) line: 358
```

Comment: which java version & jvm vendor?  any bytecode injection or rewriting going on?  custom classloaders?

Comment: What type of impossible situations are you seeing?  Are you getting Exceptions?

Comment: do you create the Field in static initializer?

Comment: Here's what happens: I have a subclass with a bunch of static final variables that are initialized. The constructor calls a superclass that puts those variables inside of a globally-accessed map. Another thread references that map via an equals method.

Example: Class B extends class A. Class B has a bunch of static final initializers. Class A constructor puts "this" into the globally accessed map. Another thread accesses this map via B.<variableName>.equals(map.get(...)). To initialize class B, those variables must be in B, yet the getter returns nothing. This only happens on rare occasions.

Comment: @lazycubiclemonkey, Do you mean 1.6.0_02 or 1.6.0_20 or Java 6 update 26?  If you are using the Unsafe class, you should be able to get the version of you JVM. :) If you want to be sure a class is loaded, why not use Class.forName()?

Comment: I've found another solution. I put all the static final initializers in a synchronized block that synchronizes on the class. This should work since class-level locking is the same lock used when the jvm is loading the class, right?

Answer (score 3):

For reference and web seaches, it turns out that you can force class initialization without using `Unsafe`:

`Class.forName(cls.getName(), true, cls.getClassLoader());`

Not pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar issue here: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43867 (search for "Unsafe" to jump to the relevant section) which might be of assistance, though it's hard to tell without more context and code...

> Tomcat, in the desire to clear out the
>   static fields within a class by using
>   reflection, has unwittingly caused the
>   class init code to be rerun due to the
>   way that reflection works.  When it
>   hits this code that tries to use the
>   log factory, it doesn't know that it
>   has already broken the logfactory by
>   setting fields within the logfactory
>   to null.

So clearing of fields by reflection (directly or by using Tomcat) could be an issue...

Comment: actually the entire idea to clear the fields of the the classes loaded by a certain classloader in order to release the classloader is weird. There are 2 ways to leak stuff, running threads (+JNI references) and references outside the web-app. The references inside the webapp won't leak anything on their own as they are outgoing, not incoming. So setting the fields to nil doesn't help much.